# How to downgrade CKEditor js library to 4.6.2 version in Django?

Tags: django, django-ckeditor

I need the old style Paste dialog. How can I use CKEditor library 4.6.2?
I am using Django 2.1.
When I install django_ckeditor 5.2.2 I get error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download version 4.6.2 here (or link to it): `cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js`, If you need the full edition the link is `cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/full/ckeditor.js`, if you need the basic edition the link is `cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/basic/ckeditor.js`.

On github you can find all the tagged versions here:  https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases

Afterwards you can link your preferred edition like this:
`<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

try to install it with `pip install django-ckeditor==3.6.2`

https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/releases/tag/3.6.2.1

Comment: there is no 4.6.2 from what i saw on the github repo

Comment: You can download version 4.6.2 here (or link to it): https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js, If you need the full edition the link is https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/full/ckeditor.js, if you need the basic edition the link is https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/basic/ckeditor.js

Comment: On github you can find all the tagged versions here: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases

Comment: @MikeS just add this in your code: <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

Comment: made an answer of it then you can mark it as solution and upvote ;-)